# How to click a button after e.preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

I tried to prevent a click() event of the
button using preventDefault() after I used unbind() to unbind the button to the event handler but it doesn't work.

```js
<script>
  $("#update2FAButton").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var providedPassword = prompt("Enter passowrd");
    var password = $("#password").val();
    if (providedPassword!==password){
      alert("Wrong password, try again.");
    }
    if (providedPassword===password){ 
      $(this).unbind(e);
      $(this).click();
    }
    

  })
</script>
```

Comment: `$(this).unbind(e);` -> `$(this).off("click");` and *possibly* you want `$(this).click();` -> `this.click();` (or explicitly `$(this)[0].click();` - ie the DOM element click).

Answer (score 0):

While `$(this).unbind` will probably work, it has been [discouraged](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/) since 1.7 and deprecated since 3.0, replaced by `$(this).off`.

The syntax for unbind/off is

```
$(this).off("eventname")
```

So in your case it would be:  `$(this).off("click")` to remove your event handler.

Separately, if you've removed the jquery event handler then `$(this).click()` will do nothing, so you need to fire click on the DOM element (rather than jquery's event):

```
this.click();
```

---

**Extra**

Note that `.off("click")` will disable *all* jquery event handlers - in this case that's likely what you want, in some cases there may be other event handlers that you don't want to remove.

You can "namespace" events and turn off just the one you want, eg:

```js
$("#clickme").on("click.runonce", function() {
    console.log("runonce");
    // yes, this could be `.one` but here to serve as an example
    $("#clickme").off("click.runonce");
});

$("#clickme").on("click.always", function() {
    // not disabled by `.off("click.runonce")`
    console.log("runalways");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clickme" type="button">click me</button>
```

Comment: Oh! thank you for the explanation sir, now I know why my code doesn't work. Btw I'm using jquery-3.5.1.